# How create table with unusual structure (html, css, js?)

Tags: html, css

I want to display the below structure using HTML tables, div or using JavaScript.

[image: image with unsusual structure]

How would I do this?

Comment: Take a look at Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Yeah... i wanted  to fix block to right top corner,  but "stamp" does't work beautifull (margin left doesn't look nice). So i decided to use css

Answer (score 1):

You could realize this with the CSS position property. If you set it to absolute, you can easily position all your div tags by using the CSS top, right, left and bottom property. I did it like this:

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

div {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 5px;
 border: 5px solid red;
}

#A {
 width: calc(75% - 20px);
 height: calc(25% - 20px);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#B {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: calc(50% - 20px);
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

#C {
 width: calc(50% - 20px);
 height: calc(25% - 20px);
 top: 25%;
 left: 0;
}

#D {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: calc(50% - 20px);
 top: 25%;
 right: 25%;
}

#E {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: calc(25% - 20px);
 right: 0;
 bottom: 25%;
}

#F {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: calc(50% - 20px);
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#G {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: calc(50% - 20px);
 bottom: 0;
 left: 25%;
}

#H {
 width: calc(50% - 20px);
 height: calc(25% - 20px);
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Unsusual structure</title>
 <link href="unsusual.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="A"></div>
 <div id="B"></div>
 <div id="C"></div>
 <div id="D"></div>
 <div id="E"></div>
 <div id="F"></div>
 <div id="G"></div>
 <div id="H"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A `table` wouldn't make sense because the premise of a `table` is to be an evenly spaced grid.

JavaScript isn't necessary, there isn't anything you could accomplish with JavaScript that you couldn't accomplish with plain CSS.

What you want is a bunch of `inline-block` elements that have predefined sizes within a container that constrains them within certain bounds and makes them wrap around and fit together that way.

As for accomplishing specifically that, I think you should make some kind of attempt on your part and come back with deliberate questions about how something works if need be.

It's kind of like asking "how do I build a car", take a mechanics class first and feel free to ask questions if you run into a problem.